# Weblogc log rotation not working as expected

Tags: server, weblogic, log-rotation

I have set log rotation(Application server log) to 10000KB of 50 files in WebLogic but it is writing to single file. Is there any other configurations have to be done other-than this log rotation configurations.

Answer (score 0):

1. Log in to Weblogic console > domain name > configuration > General Information > Advanced > lock and edit. The parameter value of the rectification configuration audit type is "change log and audit" - > Save > activate change
2. "Rotation type" is set to "by time"; "files to retain" is set to "180"; and "severity level" is set to "warning". In this case, you need to check domainlog, serverlog and accesslog.
3. The operation steps of domainlog are as follows: login to Weblogic console, domain name, configuration, logging, locking and editing, rectification, rolling type is by time, check limit the number of files to be retained, and the value of the number of files to be retained is 180, save, activate and change
4. The operation steps of serverlog are as follows: log in to Weblogic console, environment, server, servername, logging, general information, locking and editing, the rolling type of rectification is "by time", check "limit the number of files to be reserved", and the value of the number of files to be reserved is "180" - > save → activate change
5. The operation steps of accesslog are as follows: log in to Weblogic console, environment, server, servername, logging, HTTP, lock and edit the scrolling type as "by time", check "limit the number of files to be reserved", and the value of the number of files to be reserved is "180" - > save → activate and change

Comment: Turns out the LOG file was generated by managed servers & we can't have control over this file. What i got from google is this needs to handled by logrotate in linux env.

Comment: If you manually scroll and truncate the log, you can write a shell script to control it. The script judges the log size, and then uses the CP command to back up the log. The current log can use echo ">" servername.log Mode empty. The script is executed every 1 hour through a scheduled task.